# Getting an element from a specific position from a ConcurrentLinkedDeque

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, position, deque

How can i get an element from a specific position from a ConcurrentLinkedDeque just like ArrayList.get(index) ?

Thanks and regards,

Rajesh.

Comment: There is no 1 method to do this,unless you write some code

Comment: Thanks, smk. Could you briefly explain your suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConcurrentLinkedDeque` doesn't allow random access. you can only retrieve first or last element.

though you can iterate over it.

```
ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Integer> dq = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
Iterator<Integer> itr = dq.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Integer i = itr.next();
}
```

ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html

Comment: @Rajesh please note that random access on concurrent collections might exactly behave like its name: randomly! As multiple threads might change the collection concurrently, you can never be sure that the n-th element is still what it supposed to be. That's why even method `size()` is not guaranteed to return an exact value!